# Delay a method call in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know this can be done by using:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0]
```

However, the problem is that I want only 1 method call do be done.
With this function the calls will stack on top of each other. I want to make a call and if another call is made the first one will be dismissed. Ideas?

Comment: `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` performs the selector **exactly once.** I don't see what your problem is.

Comment: Are you trying to call multiple `performs` and then want to only execute the latest one ?

Comment: Yes, Inder. The exactly want I want to do. Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Once the method is executing then there is no way of stopping it.

But you can cancel if it is not fired. You can do something like this

```
//.... your code
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(myMethod) object:nil];
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
//.... your code
```

In this way you can cancel previous perform request only if the `myMethod` is not being fired.

Comment: I could perfectly use your tip for an incremental button set (here: UP and DOWN) that should not immidiatly transfer its valueset to a hardware. every tap resets the timer until the final tap fires the final value.

Answer (score 22):

In the Code Snippet Library in Xcode you can find one called GCD: Dispatch After, which looks like this:

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    <#code to be executed on the main queue after delay#>
});
```

Pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I was looking for. This implementation is great because you can make full method calls even if they have multiple parameters and it looks nice. Also, as you said, self-explanatory, both for the coder and any following developers.

Answer (score 2):

You should perform this selector in some other thread to avoid stack as you asked.
use

```
[self performSelector:(SEL) onThread:(NSThread *) withObject:(id) waitUntilDone:(BOOL)];
```

In that selector you can add delay what ever you want. As this process will run in separate thread so will not stop others for the delay

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Now that I know that you want to only use the most recent, you could instead use:

```
[self cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(myMethod) object:nil];
```

See [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget%3aselector%3aobject%3a) for more info.

ORIGINAL POST:

You could just have a BOOL that is set to NO when it reaches that section and is then reset to YES after the method is performed.

So, for example, it would look something like:

```
if (boolVal) {
    boolVal = NO;
    [self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
}
```

then in your myMethod, have:

```
boolVal = YES;
```